# How to make GroebnerBasis Work or to speed NSolve up

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, groebner-bases

I consider a set of three polynomials of two variables

```
Polyn={(0.004671149610381033724043189200478113888440102-0.325925808646329055667007855734330071329635212 I)+(0.68728976813168552981398417782014296877111780+1.67616729895363283723691400292975710594446107 I) x-(0.63829617152874386839608050490026526983150810+2.00266216305072924314325574583007067338005493 I) x^2+(1.53981001328539066542905621757610489024601619+1.67920556644760411731730020098242711096029663 I) x^3-(1.47828530500684345606280815454015431646223515-0.31566885603061204483517280735882204548230016 I) x^4+(0.26049469352739853518524342541349672028171578-1.28566865148143962811213788311832016737932204 I) x^5+(0.33493050594349093459297984056944222518488976-1.72988459093211386356860666462933068142319525 I) x^6+(1.31239305275882125546960006602735342512090039+0.31789326055026133317663000065464245271119427 I) x^7-(0.426679547648076331034658013614794258369373339+0.881556757690959640993014263859169391012861294 I) y-(0.571554993146895253755829124998212585660214703-0.020335088949544796962042219312520352996936852 I) x y-(1.11406041265012853711935333747991649005186542-1.20678953802393292304374353226949346413978893 I) x^2 y+(0.69770907066235643310158547301192696658228878-3.22855489950470904546116606171672379584588020 I) x^3 y+(1.29830268044326668173665221518494713991561652+0.23091273889590570882442404782511131451719457 I) x^4 y+(0.80397098573594239616428286139442716327745486+1.39988240453352312622064517466230818829092399 I) x^5 y-(1.53198597179298992746745871237194334636205340-0.60413892436626182263552677760324985215689543 I) x^6 y-(0.005681272303542629320287533588639452912121278-1.092357705471474502624628314067150534267269274 I) y^2+(1.12773122181646884174216193504662212088623637-0.86432568911174109393625070601702945530698096 I) x y^2-(0.137681170706644960347336850577917789011775779-0.350900708485547228446227785925989412217465418 I) x^2 y^2-(1.42214381892350918491569495378178403643467527-2.46021472898077335629899640572306345221529662 I) x^3 y^2-(1.49600108904867185418310834682345445593153823-0.50572009895526818644829857421607197927334118 I) x^4 y^2+x^5 y^2+(0.39815635125971134274942954650489471350275828-1.49804430931345695517238688070839480122278526 I) y^3-(0.683195313123056481775752128835944081326672777+0.118385215014970081569440034844688266744237834 I) x y^3-(0.842596676804253242987712782903504844534524652-0.205796782651399242268470077825322001390874321 I) x^2 y^3+(1.64539444038525270916410148549608995285014629-2.14098370674405354986303554524464465804121428 I) x^3 y^3-(1.37792072412113065938852793774883380172983548-1.62681658140698411725780379219510331682249349 I) y^4+(1.26529644044044078228622045276013384729576701-0.26854574243827645690824175126604875174653333 I) x y^4-(0.737885094704482188120782388300269503450404940-0.030333113084823398322498460634229641924743039 I) x^2 y^4+(2.54023973379056466716296536804752400375539849-2.40863822177730459640019782854712089035807763 I) y^5+(1.67743556448681494106054108902829753165876166-0.02934086410378793961668411434517909886469976 I) x y^5-(2.33107626179897231488543458198224780575068517-2.02345203069495448133007342276432729336675753 I) y^6,

(0.222664801486997648466204567151476448330769285-0.529810628084535667107138230633189236183827821 I)+(0.82361281348318643012195462689948709791743811+3.09343553267916749929266837223957189037664920 I) x-(0.87779214988742598028708716353233455529690656+3.13349013157695735594142753300356473518281441 I) x^2+(1.72925918033433334740066987949936309572606008+3.16198466584610497781631406523911296884869131 I) x^3-(2.51703234984659041071220303372302556784293827+0.86862337199133584766653081835354272227047761 I) x^4+(1.12729116509844575768251979845559881178906280-0.76928923033004102870095392393179455539054815 I) x^5-(0.06285574427808848070738889196122669646458611+2.47600115760280800204597188337157660791873248 I) x^6+(2.12329194799812184178056538025546991557227056+0.62920495981403709600673649986046918626434508 I) x^7-(0.79732724474569543853579762992589825570691179+1.51226976544789669085633019748740465042920931 I) y-(0.894248101899423699421832346992865208753294520+0.676074442757675710465867759375457793960723550 I) x y-(1.20087123786417854934975386384221409819289754-0.59082026399611801958193161174188106098010707 I) x^2 y+(3.28350438936976611604755068473730610973240218-3.06507373173016866456552844645519634045297763 I) x^3 y-(0.045011927413381919865889003548317105024905692-0.500909784236183391362339355174742892392568650 I) x^4 y+(2.56709937961339840601258561482137484091205147+0.37737020386921532034343989652886771221937040 I) x^5 y-(1.93301842125408955374436991515931984107903677-1.22555239541122150213343729668930081182733376 I) x^6 y+(0.01609716971972433216347880034134050599671301+1.95499238291235450826389287958208935677352914 I) y^2+(1.69780205816664491132254633072575451077852118+0.18355142010107168721978414755633418622961998 I) x y^2-(2.99450057896685509335497188156669522513892870-0.21353340746362070697665325510117478095975213 I) x^2 y^2-(1.30263788928645075282860875579843644467731118-1.26009466200803084119072865959780838476873873 I) x^3 y^2-(2.20691881437700548275346776012330856724963446-2.46654482718781116738555648497653300258319383 I) x^4 y^2+(0.85792328124637676846041624679873632144309215-2.56368610547306830953541537366061115980580105 I) y^3+(0.81785912819299331297975734736064770411223016-1.34525013046084092971943392587634042590283305 I) x y^3-(0.41933060775357231228212849156130251827365239-1.97200800116866865327257399110776483464375685 I) x^2 y^3+(1.79892244730664109634823239036356108820913473-3.20006317739131778342293120436681394570401502 I) x^3 y^3+x^4 y^3-(3.20604658959312515495866062928042501316913390-2.79120289368834958295106576869936423588727580 I) y^4+(0.530109229347285870448534936674650940866054247-0.526463275084290518221732085012559587605062487 I) x y^4-(1.28874239312342415558626151171691737806640753+0.73526012497920674784311138427488201161259752 I) x^2 y^4+(5.06117299470308058873646245325284119435508956-3.30204160575589943697511003332193863546073877 I) y^5+(3.34109249457709365055969939589874944258752799+0.81341090265199504925794581388831701350309680 I) x y^5-(4.33242207397378594244644090286827321609276889-2.34948427289098023256069507484268880363001610 I) y^6,

(0.408015021851838550894763858236510147595455429-0.720738605793315800504971864301419511809265156 I)+(0.62479971786367700885966553069890547384677832+4.16115790718498873236805475101653483497466308 I) x-(1.62953920638648007266065295137551709195743800+4.85058400503331689438253590306880068722421093 I) x^2+(3.24039728182860671305011123167838345727411655+3.92204277498151780462453876481237532152697660 I) x^3-(2.75992057736140893108824642507922825001007986+1.40641637793165905799774422838724009741470392 I) x^4+(1.37634321749361456436222696807034294721055131-0.94243952484311284539454542999910107633488297 I) x^5+(0.63186646248981976623048544564051247607317050-3.74888580183936485983361584092902834271465250 I) x^6+(3.18437773753860267849206490255795501644510991+1.18309281377829007962605763288365351537259048 I) x^7-(0.98081101173972721115675087140332448523933052+2.40429928194422132978543926152962269172919230 I) y+(0.20263321862237791576922364570280006463306048-1.25199292876573008800017671554523064193248256 I) x y-(1.48184927245143804303485293770751245726337652-2.41386931950858281200097054928941001449769057 I) x^2 y+(3.01511948913078118455014229176451416392514635-4.11377576321461467414833550269411331696066816 I) x^3 y+(0.18728522318354275759678638099351035417255610+1.17597279813456359639583062469212840556088480 I) x^4 y+(3.35549916844527740602712870385241499133937909+1.57499795162466849067262068483248780711490019 I) x^5 y-(3.08680671420671932685782164143548127805101485-2.06213504176589892487622285826746792518547300 I) x^6 y+(0.07489727616786745497750552197107958851923251+3.24121571854043143288356049163462446638933178 I) y^2+(1.42899775420424719629451418136225288589451661-1.28373425370560674570510077734772538227715991 I) x y^2-(2.29701175853970490666920554256422565147402636-0.01457604557454253820258049926187563010816749 I) x^2 y^2-(2.23054055092755962358068814196922686502769297-1.90519697867832570307478622903932194398724944 I) x^3 y^2-(1.90011239720192685663836591039117408070093667-2.02041720630242492978562512898534312651420371 I) x^4 y^2+(1.42973509204714432130003494006156891300558839-2.71888897641641198223154371671391894389618485 I) y^3-(0.096104069525743217434142856157145261994963672+0.524405080737081013156837403635952792211815556 I) x y^3-(0.14913634753975341218214031681332487061764594-1.67069772298447586895847552649258752596424941 I) x^2 y^3+(1.74097288787744637998314856206888665860402882-2.60695310402294810112233917706501627101690305 I) x^3 y^3-(3.69745350463130000045103753165594585010267986-2.68498638985744111463412617322869372753425951 I) y^4+(1.84204349014007609888379483625984870482168443-0.68983561975507420768556024707731708584426002 I) x y^4-(1.97962799580712697681822524998217372100020086+1.78476116861050982989186764047830594377208884 I) x^2 y^4+x^3 y^4+(6.46545749498845182176782074191976312010838769-3.65470238509105723952270094524850642425438899 I) y^5+(3.62543235618928848748623514860992887656457838+2.05685647754343298093424383668114143143325318 I) x y^5-(5.21066469498910601617209190336418287377007107-2.48370452751282532534565952230628193591862970 I) y^6}
```

To find common zeros of the polynomials I used the following:

```
Ze1 = Module[{P1 = Polyn[[1]], P2 = Polyn[[2]]}, NSolve[P1 == 0 && P2 == 0, {x, y}, 50]]; 

Ze2 = Module[{P2 = Polyn[[2]], P3 = Polyn[[3]]}, NSolve[P2 == 0 && P3 == 0, {x, y}, 50]];

Ze = Intersection[Ze1, Ze2, SameTest -> (N[#1, 1] == N[#2, 1] &)];
```

It gives the exact result, however `NSolve` takes a lot of time.

To speed up the solution process I tried to use `GroebnerBasis`:

```
Pp = Polyn; 
GB = GroebnerBasis[Pp, {y, x}, Sort -> True]; 
NSolve[GB[[1]] == 0 && GB[[2]] == 0, {x, y}, 50] // TableForm
```

Unfortunately, `GroebnerBasis` fails in this case and shows the message:

```
GroebnerBasis: Excessive loss of precision during computation.
```

How to make the `GroebnerBasis` in this case work?
Or, maybe, there are some ways to speed up `NSolve`.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why not just do `NSolve[Polyn, {y, x}]`?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, of course, this is better in general. The code I have mentioned in the question is a part of some biggest algorithm. Therefore it is written in such way.

Comment: (1) It is difficult to give a good answer when the question does not reflect the actual situation. From what has been written, I have no idea what are the salient features of the actual case(s) of interest. (2) It is unlikely that a `GroebnerBasis` computation will improve matters over `NSolve`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  
1) I am afraid , I did not understand completely what do you mean by " does not reflect the actual situation." It is actual situation. :)

2) When the polynomials have smaller total degree, then a computation of `GroebnerBasis` do improve a lot the time of computation of common zeros in comparison to `NSolve`.  I have tested this already. However with the polynomials mentioned `GroebnerBasis` does not give a result.

Comment: What I meant is that the example does not show whatever aspects cause direct use of `NSolve` not to be useful (see your remark in response to my `NSolve` suggestion). As for using `NSolve` vs preprocessing with `GroebnerBasis`, timing differences might be specific to version and `Method` setting. The example in the post seems to behave fine at least in version 11.3.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau What I can say I have tested the algorithm partially, and the part that cause the problem it this exactly this computations. Unfortunately with Mathematica 11. I can not get   `GroebnerBasis` result. Could you tell me how much time does NSolve take in version 11.3.?

Comment: It was around 2.2 seconds on my desktop machine, which is reasonably fast. I get similar in 11.1: `Timing[soln = NSolve[polys];]                                           

Out[2]= {2.2, Null}`. Are you running it differently?

Comment: Yes, my time is different, since I ask 50 digits back  `Timing[Soll = NSolve[{Pp[[1]] == 0, Pp[[2]] == 0}, {x, y}, 50];]` `{3.52136, Null}`. 

Further I need to consider langer polynomials, and it takes much more time, for example for an another setting: `Timing[ NSolve[Pp[[1]] == 0 && Pp[[2]] == 0, {x, y}, 50];]` `{13.9298, Null}` and so on.

Comment: You are trying to do something that is numerically fraught (which is why the lex GB fails, while a graded lex basis as used in `NSolve` does not). I do not know what else to suggest.

Comment: Try to use higher Precision when defining the coefficients of the polynomials. I. e. currently you specify 50 decimal digits; try 100 or 200 instead!